# Robot FrameWork : Issue when parameterizing Resource path in Settings

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

Robot Framework -I have issue parameterizing the resource path in settings section.Currently I have object repository in a file for my selenium project and saved it as `ObjectMap.Robot file`. The OR file is placed inside project . My objective is to place the `ObjectMap.Robot` in remote place to access it.

Currently I have defined the variable in the `ConfigVariables.robot`

```
*** Variables ***

${DataFilePath}    /Sample/DataFiles/
${OR_PATH}    \\\\AIX2UB333/Resources/ObjectMap/
```

The ${OR_PATH}  keep changing And to access OR file in my keyword file, I have set my setting as below.

```
*** Settings ***

Resource    ../Resources/ConfigurationFiles/ConfigVariables.robot
Resource    ${OR_PATH}/ObjectMap.robot
```

Issue : Error is shown as that

> The import name/path '${OR_PATH}/ObjectMap.robot' is parameterized.
>   Some of used parameters cannot be resolved. Use Variable mappings in
>   red.xml for parameter resolution

Tried adding to `red.xml`, the error still persist.
The funny thing is that if i run the test case it would run successfully. But the variables used from the objectmap has a red error line in test cases. Every variables has the error

> Variable is used, but not defined.

Comment: Are you just asking how to silence errors in the RED editor?

Comment: The error is shown in Resource    ${OR_PATH}/ObjectMap.robot and all variables defined in ObjectMap.robot. Basically want to know how to use variable in Resource path

Comment: Does the test run outside of red?

Comment: @BryanOakley, Could you be specific what test run outside of red means ?

Comment: Red is an editor (or more correctly, an extension to an editor). You don't need red to run robot tests.

Comment: @BryanOakley -  I created the Robot project in Eclipse , did the rest

Comment: yes, I know. red is an extension to eclipse. robot doesn't require red or eclipse or any other specific editor. You can run tests from the command line.

Comment: @BryanOakley, true. But the whole point is how can i get rid of the error shown in eclipse

Comment: _that_ is the information I was looking for. It wasn't clear if your question was about the editor, or if it was about robot tests in general. Your question isn't about robot framework _per se_, it's about how to configure and use the red editor.

Comment: @BryanOakley, you are right ? some help on that ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the red editor so I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by @Bryan Oakley, this is not a Robot Framework problem but a project configuration issue in the Eclipse RED Robot Framework editor.

It seems to me that something in your setup is not correct with respect to the project variable mapping. Please ensure that you have the latest RED by updating your eclipse from the market place or by downloading the latest from the GitHub site. I created a new project and added three files

```
project:
.
├── red.xml
├── OR
|   └── ObjectStore.robot
├── test.robot
└── resource.robot
```

test.robot

```
*** Setting ***
Resource    resource.robot
Resource    ${OR}/ObjectStore.robot

*** Test Cases ***
```

resource.robot

```
*** Variable ***
${OR}    OR
```

ObjectStore.robot

```
[EMPTY]
```

RED.xml
[image: RED.xml variable mapping]

This then ensures that no error is shown in test.robot

[image]

As your object store may change, I'd also advise not to include it in a hard coded configuration reference. Instead use the power of Robot Framework command line variable to [add a variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line) or refer to [a variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#taking-variable-files-into-use) to have the flexibility you seek without the need to modify files after fetching them from a source code repository.

Comment: Now I get an error , Path 'D:/path/ObjectMap.robot' points to location outside your workspace, when i use the code Resources  |  ${OR}/ObjectStore.robot. D:/path was given as a test purpose to view the outside location

Comment: Typically when I have an external implemented file, I keep a template one inside the workspace and use it to refer to it in the VariableMapping. At runtime I then specify the external implementation. That being said, it could be argued that this warrants a warning and not an error. If you feel like that, please log an issue at GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for the situation asked. I inserted a py file which as the code to copy ObjectMap from my remote machine to my local project and method name of this code was used as keyword in robot and applied in Suite setup. In robot I had made a flag as well to run only if the condition satify. The flag is added becos , if any one wants to run the code in the same remote machine that would create various copies of it Object Map in the same machine.

My py code

```
'def copy_file_from_source_to_destination(self,src,dst):           
    try:
        shutil.copy2(src, dst)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
    return 'Success'  '
```

My robot keyword

```
'Get Central OR

    ${DESTINATION}=    Catenate    ${EXECDIR}${TARGET_OR} 
    Log    ${DESTINATION}
    ${CALL_STATUS}=    Convert To Uppercase    ${CALL_STATUS}
    Run Keyword If    '${CALL_STATUS}'=='YES'    Copy File From Source To Destination    ${CENTRAL_OR}    ${DESTINATION}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late (I must have missed this question on SO),let me sum up above issue. RED does not know the value of variable. Variable can be modified during execution (either by testlogic,suite setups,variable files etc.) so any value assignments from Variable sections cannot be taken by RED to resolve parametrised path. The same applies to system variables such as ${EXECDIR} which can change depending where you start Robot execution and how robot command is constructed.

In another scenario, CI job, based on input parameters (for instance version or type of software to be tested with Robot) modifies variable in paths to use proper library or resource which is valid only for that version or type of software. Without VM mechanism,tester would have to temporary change suites with parametrised imports to direct paths just to be able to use proper imports (real world scenario in Nokia and the reason for VM in red.xml).

Therefore for any imports with variables in path, RED assumes that USER has to specify temporary valid values to be used during edit phase.

This is a reason for Variable Mappings in red.xml - allow to specify values of variables so any paths can be resolved thus allowing to import files.

There is also an entry in RED help (in application and on github):http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/working_with_RED/variable_mapping.html

Warning regarding "something is outside Project/Workspace" - a warning which may help to understand why tests are not working when they were checkout from repository on different machine. Any Errors/Warnings can be changed in Windows->Preferences->Robot Framework -> Error/Warnings
Help topic: http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/validation/validation_preferences.html

If you have any questions or issues,please create those on issue tracker on RED GitHub project: https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues

RED PM

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall and if you hover over one of those keywords you see: “resolved name: abspath(‘.’)” and with using the EXECDIR you need to specify the value of the EXECDIR variable, this can be set in the `PyCharm`: Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Robot Framework > Variables …I believe or specify the value of the EXECDIR variable using the robot.variables setting.

Hopefully, others can add more to the usage of EXECDIR if needed.